# Conditional include of file

Tags: autoit

I'd like to include certain script only if it's present. Unfortunately `#include` is processed before the execution, so I can't make it conditional like this:

```
If FileExists(@ScriptDir & "\common.au3") Then
   #include "common.au3"
EndIf
```

I tried to use `Execute` to evaluate the read file in place via `Execute(ReadFile(...))`. But that seems to only process single statements - I couldn't declare multiple functions for example.

Is there a different way to conditionally include another file?

Comment: It is possible but only on RUN, I mean you will not be able to compile to EXE.
Why you need this ?

Comment: You need to explain what you really want to achieve.

Comment: @MichałLipok That's fine, I don't need it compiled. I want to add some functionality which is only available as an additional / separate package provided as an extra file, similar to a plugin.

Comment: `I wouldn't be calling any undefined functions.` they "will be defined" just not processed. In any case, you should avoid situations where such action is necessary. If it is necessary it means that your UDF is not well created / written. If you don't want keep unused functions, then use Au3Stripper.

Comment: @MichałLipok That doesn't solve the case where I don't want to provide those functions to everyone. For example, when I want to sell each plugin separately.

Comment: If you attempt to compile a script which does not `#include common.au3` but which contains a variable or function defined in "common.au3", then it will fail to compile, even if the code would never be executed. ie: `If false then _common_function1()`

Comment: @garbb that's not a problem if I can include a file with empty stub implementations when a real one is not available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not a good design choice but if you really need to do somethin like this, try #OnAutoItStartRegister:

```
#OnAutoItStartRegister "_OnAutoItStart_CreateIncludes"
#include "include_collection.au3"


If IsDeclared("iExample_Common") Then
    MsgBox(64, "", "Common.au3 exists")
Else
    MsgBox(16, "", "Common.au3 wasnt included")
EndIf

MsgBox(0, "", "Your Script here")




Func _OnAutoItStart_CreateIncludes()
    If StringInStr($CmdLineRaw, '-_OnAutoItStart_CreateIncludes', 1) Then Return


    If FileExists(@ScriptDir & "\common.au3") And Not StringInStr(FileRead("include_collection.au3"), '#include "common.au3"') Then
        FileWrite("include_collection.au3", '#include "common.au3"')
    EndIf


    $iPID = Run('"' & @AutoItExe & '" ' & $CmdLineRaw & ' -_OnAutoItStart_CreateIncludes', @WorkingDir, Default, 2)
    While ProcessExists($iPID)
        ConsoleWrite(StdoutRead($iPID))
        Sleep(10)
    WEnd
    Exit
EndFunc   ;==>_OnAutoItStart_CreateIncludes
```

Create an additional empty file "include_collection.au3" as well.
In this example, I created "commons.au3" containing a statement "$iExample_commons = 1234'.

Note: Once the file is included this way, it should not be deleted otherwise your script will fail again. This could probably be overcome too but at some point it will become very messy.

Maybe it's a better Idea to wrap a launcher around your application which will add/remove include lines before startup as needed.